# Do we need different tags for [horror] and [cosmic horror]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are two tags [horror](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) and [cosmic-horror](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmic-horror). I was wondering if horror alone was enough. Cosmic-Horror is a bit too specific and does not appear much different from horror. Thoughts?

Comment: I agree, combine them into only "horror".

Comment: I'm going to disagree with this merging. Horror is a different genre from cosmic horror, which is used pretty much exclusively in the Lovecraftian sense. Downvote for disagree-ment, not mean-ness.

Comment: How can you agree or disagree with a question? I thought (dis)agreement was only for answers. @kingledion

Comment: @YoustayIgo for feature-requests, downvoting the question to indicate disagreement is common practice.  For discussion it's a mixed bag; I sometimes upvote a question *because it's good that somebody brought it up* while also upvoting an answer that says "no, don't do that".  (And I don't understand why people sometimes downvote support requests.)

Comment: I wasn't angry or even annoyed at the downvote. (I actually like most of king's answers on the main site!) It just sounded weird to downvote a question, instead of an answer. I mean it would have been very "straightforward" to downvote my answer if I supported (or opposed) an idea. @MonicaCellio

Comment: @YoustayIgo I didn't think you were angry; I was just trying to help by answering your question.

Comment: Thanks Cellio :) It did really help me :) @MonicaCellio

Answer (score 6):

I think "horror" is enough.

There are 4 questions for "horror" and 3 questions for "cosmic-horror". All of them are the same, except for one that was closed in "horror". They don't seem to be different and both don't have a description.

Therefore I think you are right: keeping the more general "horror", adding a description and removing the too specific "cosmic-horror" seems to be the best way to handle this.